# Failed to prepare device for development. XCode 13.2.1, iOS 15.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, connection, device

After upgrading the mac OS and XCode to 13.2.1 and iPhone to 15.1, the device stopped connecting to the mac. It kept showing the error as

> Failed to prepare device for development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133106?answerId=697040022#697040022) helped me where you:

- Open XCode and device manager
- Connect the device
- Shutdown the device while being connected
- Power on the device
- Wait till the device is processed by XCode in devices and simulator window

Comment: Power cycling my device fixed this for me. I didn't try and time it "while being connected".

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue with 13.2.1 and 15.4 X(

Comment: @RodrigoGomez-Palacio I have the same issue with the also with Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 15.4 on an iPhone 8 device. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @DanielBrower - if you haven't resolved, check my answer. It will probably resolve your issue.

Comment: Not working for me either, same error message shows up in the device manager

Comment: @konekoya I have not found a solution. I'm on the latest of both OS's and on Monterey.

Comment: After upgrading to the latest Xcode version of 13.3.1 fixes the issue for me :)

Answer (score 8):

Following solution work for me

1. First check compatibility version for xcode with iOS version from following https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/
2. Now check the list of devices support to your Xcode from 'Device Support'
3. To get into 'Device Support' :: Open Finder -> Applications -> Scroll to Xcode -> Right Click -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport This is the list of devices folder support for your Xcode
4. Now check for your iOS version from iPhone device :: Open Settings from iPhone -> General -> About -> Software Version
5. If the 'Device Support' folder does not contains the folder of your iPhone iOS Version, then you need to add respective folder from following link https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport
6. From above Github page, select device version & download zip file
7. Now extract file & you will get the folder for your iOS version
8. Copy this folder into Finder -> Applications -> Scroll to Xcode -> Right Click -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport
9. Disconnect device (if connected), restart xcode
10. Before connecting device, delete derived data from xcode & clean cache using cmd + shft + k. Then make sure to reset 'Location & Privacy' from device :: From iPhone device go to Settings -> General -> Transfer or Rest Phone -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy -> Enter passcode to continue
11. Now connect your iPhone device with macbook (through cable), xcode will detect your device & you can run your application

Comment: This working for me - (iOS 16.4, Xcode 14.2). Thanks a lot.

Comment: This worked for me too - (iOS 16.4, Xcode 14.2). Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, that I was looking for one day. (IOS 16.4(Zip FIle), Xcode 14.2 ) worked on Phone OS 16.6 as well. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

Re: Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 15.4

You may need to update to the latest version of Xcode. If you just updated your phone OS, then Xcode may not support the latest OS. You can find Xcode 13.3.1 (or higher) on the App Store. You'll need to update to Monterey as well though.

Comment: 13.3 also has some issues when publishing a build with an AdHoc profile. So I'd recommend upgrading to 13.3.1 instead

Answer (score -1):

**Simple Solution**:

You just need to **update Xcode** version from 13.2.1 to higher version available on [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).