# Xcode "Failed to prepare device for development."

Tags: xcode

(Xcode 13.2.1) When I run an Xcode project onto my iPad, it says "Failed to prepare device for development" and stops.

I tried all the solutions; restarting the device and Mac, cleaning the build folder, updating both devices, but none of them work. How can I get past this?

Comment: Upgrade your copy of Xcode?

Comment: Have the same issue with the latest iOS and Xcode versions
This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70734102/3534964