# Why does Xcode think that I have an iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

but I have an iPhone 13 plugged into my MacBook Pro. I know this might seem like a strange question, but when I try to build & run my app the following messages notify me

```
This iPhone 4 is running iOS 15.6.1 (19G82), which may
not be supported by this version of Xcode. An updated
version of Xcode may be found on the App Store or at
developer.apple.com.
```

[image: image of the text provided]

I cannot remember when the following notification came to my attention, but it basically displays the same message and I took a screenshot of it when it occurred

[image: same error message in a different place]

I have contacted Apple, but I am on my second tech, who is asking me about my browser version, etc... which tells me that they are stalling - no browser, an app build & run in Xcode. An app literally targeting iOS 11.0 and above

Comment: Did you add an older iPhone 4 with the same name ? Try to get latest version of xCode.

Comment: @ptit-xav The iPhone 4 that I had over decade ago could possibly have the same name - do not know for sure, but the one that I have now, is basically my actual name plus the word phone, so it is possible to be the same name. Is there a way to change the name of my current phone? As far as the latest version of Xcode goes, when I go into the App Store and search for Xcode, there is no update/upgrade button to click, which makes me assume that I have the latest - 11.3.1

Comment: Settings / general / information / name . Personnaly i always set a new name si I can use also the older one.

Comment: @PtitXav I really thought that was going to work. I was able to change the name of the phone, as you suggested. Xcode displayed the name of the device had changed, but when I go to run the app, I still receive the notification that "iPhone 4..." I had hope that changing the name of the phone was going to work. Thank you for your help, but there has to be a setting for Xcode not to look for iPhone 4 support files

Comment: Which version of xCode are you running ?

Comment: @PtitXav Sorry for the lag in response. I was working the lunch shift - Xcode version 11.3.1 MacOS 10.14.6

Comment: I don’t think xCode 11 is compatible with iPhone 13 with iOS 15. If you can’t install a more recent xCode (supporting iOS 15) You need to «manually » add iOS 15 directory from xcode 13 inside your xCode 11 . You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72144045/13944750) .

Comment: Look also at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974291/xcode-error-failed-to-prepare-device-for-development)

Comment: @PtitXav First, you are correct Xcode 11 only supports up to 13.2 and thanks for the link to the post, because I was able to download the support for iOS 15, but believe it or not, now my Xcode does not recognize that my iPhone is connected to my MacBook Pro. When I choose, "no device..." it recognizes my iPhone, but after clicking the "Done" button, it is back to not listing my iPhone - WTF

Comment: BTW, in case someone else has this issue with suddenly loosing the ability to recognize your iPhone. Within Xcode, I went into the Unity-iPhone>Build Settings> changed Base SDK and Supported Platforms to iOS

Comment: May be related to the fact that serial number are now random. Before the device type could be determined by serial number. May be your phone as a serial number which could be valid for an iPhone 4 . Changing base SDK to upper one may have help this. (That is just a guess)